# What is the purpose of putting an immediate value in parens in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

What, if anything, is the difference between these two instructions?

```
subs    r2, r2, #(32)

subs    r2, r2, #32
```

What are the parentheses `()` for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, those are parentheses, not brackets.

There is no difference between:

```
subs    r2, r2, #(32)
```

and

```
subs    r2, r2, #32
```

I suspect the `(32)` used to be something like `(32 - 8)` or something that was interesting / meaningful / necessary at the time, then the "`- 8`" was removed but the parentheses were simply kept since they do no harm.

---

*For the sake of completeness, even though it's not what you asked & you probably already know it:*

The code

```
LDR r0, [r1]
```

with "brackets" (register indirect) loads `r0` with the value whose address is stored in `r1` -- in other words, if `r1` holds 1000, `r0` will be loaded from MEM[1000]

Comment: Yeah, I used the wrong wording, but I know the difference. Found out the coder was just being inconsistent. Thanks!